# Yajra Datatables and Entrust package

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, package

I'm working with role based permission using Zizaco Entrust package with yajra datatables.
when i'm giving permission to some users i have to touch datatables also.
This is my code ,

```
   Controller.php
             Datatables::of(User::where('company_id',$company_id)->get())
                ->addColumn('action', '@permission('user-edit')
    <a href="{{route("users.show",$id)}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">View</a>@endrole
            <a href="{{route("users.edit",$id)}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Edit</a>')
           ->make(true);
```

when i use permission inside datatables it is getting error , any one having idea to solve this ??same question in 
[yajra datatables and entrust role permission laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848347/yajra-datatables-and-entrust-role-permission-laravel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Entrust::can()` checks if the user is logged in, and then if user has the permission. If the user is not logged the return will also be false.

Check below code:

```
Datatables::of(User::where('company_id',$company_id)->get())
    ->addColumn('action', function($company){
        $action = '';
        if (!Entrust::can('user-edit')) {
            $action = '<a href="' . route("users.show",$id) . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">View</a>';
        }
        $action .= '<a href="' . route("users.edit",$id) . '" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Edit</a>';
        return $action;
    })
->make(true);
```

Made correction into code for `{{}}` and quotes issue.

Comment: Yeah it's working for me.. Thanks for your reply.. !!

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow this technique

```
->addColumn('actions', function($admin) {
    return  view('admin.user.partials.admin_action', compact('admin'))->render();
})
```

And in your blade admin_action, you can write your view code as follows

```
@permission("admin-edit")
<a href="#" title="Edit"
class="btn-sm btn-primary editData"
data-id="{{ $admin->id }}"
data-fname="{{ $admin->f_name }}"
data-lname="{{ $admin->l_name }}"
data-email="{{ $admin->email }}"
data-redeem_manager="{{ $admin->redeem_manager }}"
data-mobile="{{ $admin->mobile }}"
data-role_id="{{ $admin->role_id }}"
><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> </a>
@endpermission
```

Answer (score 0):

Entrust::can() not working with me causes an error.

but \Auth::user()->can('user-edit') works well with me

```
return datatables()->of($data)
                ->addColumn('actions', function ($data) {
                    $button = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="' . route('users.show', $data->id) . '" >Show <i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>';
                    if (\Auth::user()->can('user-edit')) {
                        $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="' . route('users.edit', $data->id) . '" >Edit <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>';
                    }
                    if (\Auth::user()->can('user-delete')) {
                        $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a id="' . $data->id . '" class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="#" >Delete <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>';
                    }
                    return $button;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['actions'])
                ->make(true);
```